# Underscore Equivalent to Javascript For Loop?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'd like to convert this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < product.ages.length; i ++){
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.ages.length; j ++){
        if (product.ages[i].id == $scope.ages[j].id){
            $scope.ages[j]['ticked'] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

into underscore.js. please help.

Comment: A for-loop like iteration would be [_.each](http://underscorejs.org/#each).

Comment: It's a shame there isn't an easily accessible list of Underscore methods that you could've consulted. [Oh, wait...](http://underscorejs.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to solve this problem would be to first create a hash of the scope.ages using underscore's [**indexBy**](http://underscorejs.org/#indexBy):

```
var scope_ages = _.indexBy($scope.ages, 'id');
```

The object would look something like:

```
{
    1: ref to scope.ages with id 1,
    2: ref to scope.ages with id 2,
    etc.
}
```

Then iterate over the product ages using [**each**](http://underscorejs.org/#each) to set the ticked value:

```
_.each(product.ages, age => scope_ages[age.id].ticked = true)
```

```js
var product = {
 ages: [
  { id : 1 }
 ]
}

var $scope = {
 ages: [
  { id : 0, ticked: false },
  { id : 1, ticked: false },
  { id : 2, ticked: false },
 ]
}

var scope_ages = _.indexBy($scope.ages, 'id');

_.each(product.ages, age => scope_ages[age.id].ticked = true)

document.getElementById('scope_ages').textContent = JSON.stringify(scope_ages);
document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify($scope.ages);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore.js"></script>

<h1>scope_ages</h1>
<p>
    <pre id="scope_ages"></pre>
</p>
<h1>Scope</h1>
<p>
  <pre id="result"></pre>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be your code in underscore:

```
_.each(product.ages, function(pAge) {
  _.each($scope.ages, function(sAge) {
    if (pAge.id === sAge.id) {
      sAge.ticked = true;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how you do an _.each on an object.

```html
var example = {"hello":"world", "this":"is", "super":"neat"};
_.each(example, function(value, index){
  console.log(index + ":" + value);
}
->hello:world
->this:is
->super:neat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.find`

```js
_.each($scope.ages, function(v){
  v.ticked = _.find(product.ages, function(a){
    return v.age === a.age;
  })?true:false;
})
```

Also, just a pointer, you should use `break` on match.